# SQL Using WITH and JOIN together to create a view efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I'm trying to use data from one table named `period` which specifies what period a date falls into, then using that instance to join into another table using the following statement.

```
WITH rep_prod AS (
    SELECT t.tran_num, t.amount, t.provider_id, t.clinic, 
    t.tran_date, t.type, t.impacts, p.period_id, p.fiscal_year, p.period_weeks
    FROM transactions t, period p
    WHERE tran_date BETWEEN period_start AND period_end
)

SELECT r.tran_num, r.amount, r.provider_id, d.first_name, d.last_name, 
d.clinic, r.tran_date, r.period_id, r.period_weeks, r.type, r.impacts
FROM rep_prod AS r
INNER JOIN provider AS d
ON r.provider_id = d.provider_id AND r.clinic = d.clinic
```

Looking to create this as a view on my DB, is there a more efficient way to accomplish this? This is currently holding around 6.2 million rows and it will only continue to get bigger. This query alone took over 7 minutes to complete, granted I'm using SQL Express with the memory limitations.

Update: Change query to reflect the removal of the `SELECT DISTINCT` function

EDIT: @Rabbit So you're suggesting something like this?

```
SELECT t.tran_num, t.amount, t.provider_id, d.first_name, d.last_name, 
d.clinic, t.tran_date, p.period_id, p.period_weeks, p.fiscal_year, p.period_start, p.period_end, t.type, t.impacts
FROM transactions t
    INNER JOIN provider d
        ON provider.provider_id = transactions.provider_id AND provider.clinic = transactions.clinic
    INNER JOIN period p
        ON t.tran_date BETWEEN p.period_start AND p.period_end
```

Comment: The prodids subquery seems unnecessary.

Comment: Why wouldn't the period table be distinct already? Also, the CTEs are unnecessary. You can just join transaction to period to provider without using the CTE. Have you set up the proper indexes?

Comment: I was using `SELECT DISTINCT` due to the source table I originally pulled it from having a period 0 value with didn't amount to anything. But I believe you are right that it is unnecessary. However I don't think I can just join all 3 tables, my `period` table does not have any values that I can join on between either of the other tables, it is purely a reference table to determine what period a transaction falls in.

Comment: I agree with @Rabbit the CTE does not appear necessary.  Whilst using SQL Express indexing is only your only option.  You seem to be able to do this with t.provider = d.provider and t.clinic = d.clinic.  Im a little skeptical about your trandates and period dates (This could be why you need the CTE)  is period id an FK in any other table?

Comment: @OMAsphyxiate you do have something to join on: tran_date BETWEEN period_start AND period_end